# Updating text within NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsobject, nsmutablestring

I create a NSMutableAttributedString in the init method of a view by doing this:

```
self.name = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Gabe Jacobs"];
```

How do I update the string within it without initing again? I don't want to have to create a new one every time. Any idea?

Comment: If you had read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you would have perceived the `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:`, `replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:` and various other mutation methods...

Comment: @user529758 - If everyone got all of their answers from documentation (which is often obscured and packed with knowledge that may not be pertinent at the moment) then there would be little use for a QA site such as this.  We help people in this community, Mr. "Im gonna use an anonymous handle and be a jerk", haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"first"];
[string replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) withString:@"second"];
```